# Wrong number of arguments for a simple function

Tags: clojure

Can someone explain the behavior in the Clojure code below?
I don't get it.
Does Clojure somehow replace or "optimize" function arguments? Why does calling a function with a single nil argument result in an `ArityException`?

```
(defn foo [bar] (reduce #(%1) bar))

(foo nil)
-> ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: test$foo$fn  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `(doc reduce)`:

> [...]
>   If coll contains no
>   items, f must accept no arguments as well, and reduce returns the
>   result of calling f with no arguments.
>   [...]

Here coll is `nil`, which is effectively being treated as a collection containing no items (as it usually is in similar contexts), and `f` is `#(%1)`.

Thus `#(%1)` is being called with no arguments and ends up throwing the exception you see.

Comment: I see. So my error was overlooking `$fn` in the error message. Not `foo` but `#(%1)` is throwing the `ArityException`.